# How do I modify DATABASES variable when including local_settings.py from a django settings.py

Tags: django, django-settings

At the top of settings.py I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'pw'
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

At the bottom I have:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

In the local_settings.py, I'd like to modify DATABASES['default']['host'] that is defined in the settings.py file.

Is this possible?  If so, how?  I don't want to duplicate the whole DATABASES setting, I just want to adjust the HOST (to point at another server).

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your `settings.py`.

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
    for k,v in _DATABASES:
        if k in DATABASES:
            DATABASES[k].update(v)
        else:
            DATABASES[k] = v
except ImportError:
    pass
```

With something like this in your `local_settings.py`.

```
_DATABASES = {"default":{"HOST":"new_host"}}
```

**EDIT:** Note I've changed my code per @saverio's comment about nested dictionaries.

Comment: Wrong. This would override the full "default" database definition with one with just the "HOST" key. You'd better define some different keys in "local_settings" and use getattr(local_settings, key, default_value) in your main settings module.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, my bad, I typed that out on my phone so I wasn't thinking too clearly. @saverio is correct in that because these are nested `dict`s they want auto-magically recursively update themselves. I think that because we can assume there is only one level of nesting in the dictionaries you can safely use the new code I've changed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in local_settings.py:

```
import settings

settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = 'my_host'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, since I'm importing local_settings from settings, that seems like an infinite import loop.

Comment: Python interpreter will take care of it - it's optimized not to import the same module twice. Besides, I have tested this solution before suggesting. Give it a try, man!

Answer (score 0):

typically I reverse it, so settings.py overrides local_settings.py `from local_settings import *` at the top of settings.py. Normally db settings are on location based setting, i.e. dev db for dev work and really do not add db settings to settings.py.  In my mind settings.py should define settings that are required in every location that the project is running and shouldn't be over written by a subset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execfile()` instead of an import. That gives you access to everything in settings.py's scope:

```
execfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'local_settings.py'))
```